# is it possible that can create an object from class person inside a class employee and access to the methods in C#.net

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

Can I create an object from class person inside a class employee and access to the methods and members of class person through employee class using the person’s object that I created in class employee

```
public class Person
{
    protected string _name;
    public int _age;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
}

class Employee
{
    Person person = new Person();
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Did yo try it before asking ?

Comment: why not just `public class Employee { public Person PersionalInfo {get; set;} /* other Employee properties*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
public class Employee
{
    private Person person = new Person();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return person.Name; }
        set { person.Name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return person.Age; }
        set { person.Age = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
class Employee
{
    Person person = new Person();

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return person.Name; }
        set { person.Name = value } 
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return person.Age; }
        set { person.Age = value; }
    }
}
```

You could look at providing a 'person' interface and letting the employee class implement it.

Comment: thank you. i forgot to put the object inside method. coz i put it outside method.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because class Person is public.